# Using a verb with -ing after "rather than"

Tags: grammar

Can I put 'creating' in place of 'create' in this sentence?

> Robots are expected to eliminate jobs rather than **create** them.
>
> Robots are expected to eliminate jobs rather than **creating** them.

Dictionaries define 'rather than' is at times a conjunction, at others a compound preposition. And I've checked out the similar case in this site. But I'm not quite sure of this specific sentence being grammatically right.

Answer (score 4):

It's best to employ [parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) in a sentence like this, so that the "eliminate" part matches up with the "create" part. Therefore, you'd probably want to use something like either one of these:

> Robots are expected to **eliminate** jobs rather than **create** them.
>
> It is expected that robots will be **eliminating** jobs rather than **creating** them.

So, yes, you can use *creating* instead of *create*, but you should restructure the sentence in order to do so.